# Why doesn't using return inside the code block end my function? Not sure why I keep getting " Cannot set property 'currentTime' of null"

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a JavaScript script that when the user presses a key on the keyboard, if it's one of the assigned keys, the script plays the corresponding sound. If the user presses a key that isn't a sound key, for instance, "R", then I want the script to end. Right now, it returns: "Cannot set property 'currentTime' of null" even though I tried to end it with if (audio == false) return;

I'm also curious what the rules are for writing a condition statement with the code block following it being on the same line. (I'm following a tutorial and it's the first time I'm seeing it done this way.)

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    var audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`)
    console.log(audio)

    // this function stops the function if you press a button that doesn't have a corresponding sound 

    if (audio == false) return;

    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should be checking for null explicitly with ===. In the interactive console try typing `false == null` and see what you get. The rules for this stuff are a little finicky so default to the explicit check unless you're sure how they apply.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, if the result of `document.querySelector` does not exist, it will not set `audio` to `false`, it will return `null`.  This means that `audio == false` will not return `true`.

You probably want this:

```
if(audio === null)
```

Comment: When I implement this code, it still logs 'null' when I press a key without an audio sound. In the example, it doesn't get null, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I am guessing it logs null because you have console.log(audio) before it runs.

Answer (score 0):

That's because only undefined and null itself are abstractly equal to null.

```js
console.log(null == null);      // true
console.log(undefined == null); // true
console.log(false == null);     // false
```

In this case I would just coerce to boolean:

```
if (!audio) return;
```

Comment: Can you tell me a little bit more about why you are using 1 line and no brackets? Also, when I implement this code, it still logs 'null' when I press a key without an audio sound. In the example, which uses the same code as you recommend, it doesn't get null, but for some reason I keep getting it...

Comment: @FaiqueMoqeet It's like `if (!audio) { return; }`. You don't need braces if you have a single statement.

Comment: Okay, I figured, just never came across it before. Thanks.